# Getting date in salesforce case

Tags: case, date, field-update, case-object

I am a bit new to salesforce. I have made a web to case form that I have to use on goolge sites. I have made the HTML data picklist for day, month and year. How can I get all these three in salesforce as a date format. I tried by creating a custom field and putting the ID of that custom field in the form but still the date field is empty.

Any help will be much appreciated

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post the code to see what you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that - The format for Date and Currency fields is taken from your Organisation defaults.

Next what you can do is, try something like -

```
<input id="00N80000003LGJ5" name="00N80000003LGJ5" type="text" size="25">
 <a href="javascript:NewCal('00N80000003LGJ5','ddmmyyyy')">
 <img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date">
 </a>
 </input>
```

Follow the instructions to upload the JS and image from this site 
**http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tengcalendar.shtml**

**00N80000003LGJ5** is ID of your Date field. (Enter correct one) 
 
**ddmmyyyy** is format that Salesforce accepts. (Enter correct one)

This is just for illustration purpose. You can google and find bunch of Javascript date pickers online. 
Hope this helps!